# No such module ‘AWSCore’ when running my CI, it's fine locally

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, aws-amplify, bitrise

I’ve had a weird issue on my iOS CI pipeline on Bitrise, and I it’s been happening ever since:

- Upgrading my local machine to MacOS Montery Beta (12)
- Upgrading to Xcode 13 (I was using the beta until now). I’m now on 13.1

The Bitrise stack is set up to use MacOS Big Sur and Xcode 13.0.

The archive step is failing due to the following error:

```
❌ /Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Carbn-aytoffoummsttefoksamtqdxyipu/SourcePackages/checkouts/amplify-ios/AmplifyPlugins/Core/AWSPluginsCore/Auth/AWSAuthService.swift:10:8: no such module 'AWSCore'
```

I’m using AWS Amplify with Swift Package Manager as a dependency, and I haven’t changed anything about it since long before this was broken.

When I try to run my code and create archives on my local device, it works fine - I have not been able to recreate this error anywhere except on Bitrise.

I have attempted...

- Removing and re-installing the AWS Amplify dependency
- Rebuilding using an older version of Xcode (12.4) and pushing that up
- Doing the same with multiple MacOS Montery beta versions (the issue has existed through multiple betas)
- Attempting to use alternative Xcode 12.x versions on Bitrise (this is no longer possible since my project uses iOS 15+)

I’m at a loss to how to proceed - any help will be hugely appreciated since the lack of CI is slowing down our dev/test/release cycles pretty badly!

Thank you for any help or ideas you can give.

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the AWSCore problem - I both re-installed the SPM package and added `$(BUILD_PRODUCT_DIR) ------ recursive` to my framework search paths.

I  now have this error:

```
❌  /Users/vagrant/git/App/Carbn/Application/App Coordinator/Flows/AppCoordinator+HomeFlow.swift:19:8: no such module 'Challenges'
import Challenges
        ^
```

Challenges is a feature module in my project. I recently renamed it, but made sure there is no trace of the previous name anywhere in the project. I got 20 of the above error (I think everywhere that imports it) and the following other warning:

```
⚠️  /Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Carbn-aytoffoummsttefoksamtqdxyipu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Carbn-Test/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Carbn.build/Testing-iphoneos/Carbn.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppCoordinator+FlowDelegate.dia:1:1: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'Carbn' from project 'Carbn')
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
       ^
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the exact same error, on Bitrise only, under the exact same circumstances as you. Adding `$(BUILD_PRODUCT_DIR)` recursively to Framework Search Paths fixed it for whatever reason.

Comment: Has anyone reached out to Bitrise and filed an issue report with them? I’m having the exact same issue exclusively within a Bitrise environment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this now - I'll keep it here for posterity.

I hadn't renamed the FOLDER (separate from the Xcode project) to the new module name. Changing this solved everything.